# Running project on VS for mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, visual-studio

I'm trying to run project on Visual studio for Mac preview.
Version of vs: Preview 2(7.0 build 560).

The first thing which I did, it was setting the debug information to none (because of problems connected with it).
Right now I'm getting this type of error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not find file "/Users/.../.../..../.../bin\roslyn\csc.exe".

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
```

I was trying to search for this problem but I couldn't find anything useful.

Project is made in ASP.NET MVC 5

Thanks for any help guys

Comment: MVC 5 projects are not qualified in many cases as Mono is not .NET Framework. You might remove the Roslyn related NuGet packages from this project and try again. But keep in mind that only ASP.NET Core projects are truly cross platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is probably using Roslyn compiler and/or tools that produce PDB files instead of MDB.

PDB files are unsupported by Mac and that's why You need to delete these two nuget packages:

`"Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform"`

`"Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0"`

This isn't perfect solution but for my purposes it was a good workaround.